# duplicate entry at key primary mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My program is really simple it inserts the same value in one column and updates the timestamp and date on another column. It also has an auto incrementing ID column that acts as the table's primary key.

```
+-------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id    | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| Power | float      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| dt    | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

at the moment I'm stuck with `id = 4000` `Power = 40996` and `dt = recent date time`

As soon as i try to run a command that inserts data into the table, I get an error that states

> duplicate entry '4971' for key 'primary'

check table:

```
+----------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                  |
+----------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| newdb.newmeter | check | warning  | Table is marked as crashed                                |
| newdb.newmeter | check | warning  | 19 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly |
| newdb.newmeter | check | warning  | Size of datafile is: 68816       Should be: 68663         |
| newdb.newmeter | check | error    | Found 4048 keys of 4039                                   |
| newdb.newmeter | check | error    | Corrupt                                                   |
+----------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: insert into newdb.newmeter (Power) values (40997);

Comment: @piotrm insert into newdb.newmeter (Power) values (40997);

Comment: @piotrm sorry but i'm not stuck at 4000 in id column but its 4970 so next one is 4971 thats where i'm getting above error.

Comment: you can try checking your table for corruption - CHECK TABLE newmeter;

Comment: @piotrm thanks mate for this i've updated my post with answer it looks horrible. how do i fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your data.
If you can afford to shutdown mysqld you should do it and use [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisamchk.html) to repair table.
If it is not an option try doing FLUSH TABLES; and REPAIR TABLE newmeter;
Be prepared for data in your table being not very accurate.

Comment: thanks piotrm "repair table" worked and now i'm able to use the same table again. but i feel like this going to take really long time to build the database worht of the year time i'm sure there is some thing i can do in excel and dump the file straight to mysql so i can have database with date time stamp of a year. any suggestion? thanks much for the help

Comment: I would advise against using excel or anything that is not related to mysql itself. Just make sure to always have a copy of table files you backed up and try different things, using instructions in mysql online manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-repair.html